# Problems coercing factors into intergers

Tags: r, coercion

I am trying to convert a factor (tickets_other) in a data frame (p2) into an integer. Following the R help guide, as well as other advice from others, this code should work:

```
as.numeric(levels(p2$tickets_other))[p2$tickets_other]
```

The column does contain NAs, and so I get a warning:

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Which is fine, but after coercing it to numeric, it still reads as a factor:

```
class(p2$tickets_other)
[1] "factor"
```

The same result happens if I use as.numeric(as.character.()):

```
as.numeric(as.character(p2$tickets_other))
Warning message: 
NAs introduced by coercion 
class(p2$tickets_other)
[1] "factor"
```

Comment: Please provide some data

Comment: Post output of command 'head(p2)' or 'head(p2$tickets_other)' here.

Comment: Without looking at your data. I'm guessing you need `as.numeric(as.character(p2$tickets_other))`

Comment: doesn't look like you're resetting p2$tickets_other with the result of your conversion?  nothing will change if you don't store the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was actually very simple. The command:

```
as.numeric(levels(p2$tickets_other))[p2$tickets_other]
```

is correct, but I failed to store the result:

```
p2$tickets_other <- as.numeric(levels(p2$tickets_other))[p2$tickets_other]
```

Simple mistake, it retrospect. Thanks to DMT for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing:

```
as.numeric(levels(p2$tickets_other))[p2$tickets_other]
```

You are reading the levels from `p2$tickets_other` (a vector), then converting them to numeric (still a vector), then accessing the indices of that vector according to the values in `p2$tickets_other`

I can't imagine this is what you really want to do.

Maybe just

```
as.numeric(p2$tickets_other)
```

is what you want?